# Retrofit2+RxJava2, Invalid token, how to update stream when retryWhen() re-subscribe

Tags: rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2, reactive, resque-retry

I have this simple code below that simulates a scenario Im currently trying to accomplish

```
mApiService.api().postSomethingWithAccessToken(request, "some_invalid_access_token")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .retryWhen(new Function<Observable<Throwable>, ObservableSource<AccessToken>>() {

                @Override
                public ObservableSource<AccessToken> apply(Observable<Throwable> throwableObservable) throws Exception {
                    return mApiService.api().getAccessToken();
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Void value) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    onError(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                }
            });
```

Ill just enumerate it to make my goal clear:

1. perform a **POST** call with a current access token
2. if it receives an appropriate error (404,403, 401 or such)
3. perform a **GET** call to have a fresh access token
4. retry the whole sequence using the new access token

based on the code above and my understanding so far with **.retryWhen()**, is that it will execute if an error happened on the original **Observable**( .**postSomethingWithAccessToken()**), and retrying if necessary (based on your conditions inside retry), what happens here is that the **.retryWhen()** executes first before the outer Observable, causing undesired duplicate request, 
how can I achieve those things I mentioned above, based on my current understanding(code)? Any help will be greatly appreciated. :(

Edit: Current workaround:

```
mApiService.api().postSomethingWithAccessToken(request, preferences.getString("access_token", ""))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .retryWhen(new Function<Observable<Throwable>, ObservableSource<?>>() {

                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> apply(final Observable<Throwable> throwableObservable) throws Exception {

                    return throwableObservable.flatMap(new Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<?>>() {

                        @Override
                        public ObservableSource<?> apply(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

                            if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {

                                HttpException httpException = (HttpException) throwable;

                                if (httpException.code() == 401) {

                                    return mApiService.api().getAccessToken()
                                            .doOnNext(new Consumer<Authentication>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void accept(Authentication authentication) throws Exception {
                                                    update(authentication);
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            }

                            return Observable.error(throwable);
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Observer<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    Log.e("subscribe", "TOKEN : " + preferences.getString("access_token", ""));
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Void value) {
                    Log.e("onNext", "TOKEN : " + preferences.getString("access_token", ""));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.e("Complete", "____ COMPLETE");
                }
            });
```

Method that updates the token via shared preference

```
public void update(Authentication authentication) {
    preferences.edit().putString("access_token", authentication.getAccessToken()).commit();
}
```

I noticed that(i put a Log) the outer observable's subscribe and the retryWhen was executed at main thread, but the stream of retrying/resubscribing is jumping over different Scheduler's thread, it seems like a race condition :(

```
    onSubscrbie_outer_observable: Thread[main,5,main]
    RetryWhen: Thread[main,5,main]
    Throwable_FlatMap: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
    doOnNext(Token_Refresh): Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
    Throwable_FlatMap: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-2,5,main]
    doOnNext(Token_Refresh): Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-2,5,main]
    Throwable_FlatMap: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
    doOnNext(Token_Refresh): Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
    // and so on...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few problems here:

- you need to pass back the access token to the `postSomethingWithAccessToken` method when retrying, otherwise you'll just retry with the same old invalid access token.
- your retry when logic is incorrect, you must respond to the errors `Observable` you get and put your retry logic there. as you were saying this method is executed first, not when error happens, the `throwableObservable` is what response to error, it will mirror errors as emissions (`onNext()`), you can `flatMap()` each error and response either with error (for delivering error to the source stream) complete , or with `onNext()` with some object to signal it to retry.
  A great [blog post ban Dan Lew](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/) on this subject.

So you need:
1) to store the Access Token somewhere where you can change it with access token refresh.
2) fix the retry when logic to respond properly to errors

Here's a suggestion code:

```
postSomethingWithAccessToken(request, accessToken)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .retryWhen(new Function<Observable<Throwable>, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                   @Override
                   public ObservableSource<?> apply(
                           @NonNull Observable<Throwable> throwableObservable) throws Exception {
                       return throwableObservable.flatMap(
                               new Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<? extends R>>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public ObservableSource<? extends R> apply(
                                           @NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                                       if (throwable.code == 401) { //or 404/403, just a pseudo-code, put your real error comparing logic here
                                           return getAccessToken()
                                                           .doOnNext(refreshedToken -> accessToken.updateToken(refreshedToken));
                                                   //or keep accessToken on some field, the point to have mutable
                                                   //var that you can change and postSomethingWithAccessToken can see
                                       }
                                       return Observable.error(throwable);
                                   }
                               });
                       }
                   }
        )
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<Result>() {
                       @Override
                       public void accept(@NonNull Result result) throws Exception {
                           //handle result
                       }
                   }
        );
```

Comment: hello, thanks so much for providing a code sample and mentioning mistake points, if its not too much to ask ,would you mind to change the code into non-lambda?,

Comment: thanks so much!, ill get to it, ill try to rework my code. :) , thanks for the link too :)

Comment: just a question, is it really normal that retryWhen() executes first? before the actual outer observable execution? - i dont know if I understand this correctly -> "The factory Func1 is called on subscription to setup the retry logic. That way, when onError is called, you've already defined how to handle it."

Comment: yes, as it's explained, the retry logic is first constructed by your Func1 method, then the throwableObservable will subscribe and only then the source Observable. that's why you can't perform actual work there, you should integrate your retry logic inside throwableObservable stream. meaning the retry is based on reacting to throwableObservable  error emissions and not and the Func1 method body.

Comment: your suggested code is completely working, Im just having some issues with updating the token even as static variable or an object field making the the retry non-stop,  anyway, "the retry logic is first constructed by your Func1 method, then the throwableObservable will subscribe and only then the source Observable." - thank you , this is a good head start for me :) :) thank you thank you

Comment: hello again, would you mind if you guide me on how to update the source of the token? I have posted my current implementation, I tweaked a bit your suggested code above, and it worked liked a charm, but it keeps using the same accessToken, it doesnt update even as field, static, now in this case, the token is saved via preference, it keeps on using the old token :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142149/discussion-between-yosriz-and-robert).

Answer (score 1):

BIG Thanks to yosriz as he pointed me in the right direction to solve my teeth-grinding problem, I have to use `defer`. So I ended up with this issue in GitHub, [Why resubscribe the source observable emit same output when I use retryWhen operator?](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4840)

It's exactly the same issue I'm having right now, for anyone experiencing the same issue here here is my solution.

```
Observable
    .defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<?>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<?> call() throws Exception {
            // return an observable source here, the observable that will be the source of the entire stream;
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn( /*target thread to run*/ )
    .retryWhen( {
        // return a throwable observable here that will perform the logic when an error occurred
    })
    .subscribe( /*subscription here*/ )
```

or here is the full non-lambda of my solution

```
Observable
    .defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<?>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<?> call() throws Exception {
            return mApiService.api().postSomethingWithAccessToken(
                request, preferences.getString("access_token", ""));
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .retryWhen(new Function<Observable<Throwable>, ObservableSource<?>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<?> apply(final Observable<Throwable> throwableObservable) throws Exception {
            return throwableObservable.flatMap(new Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> apply(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
                        HttpException httpException = (HttpException) throwable;
                        if (httpException.code() == 401) {
                            return mApiService.api().getAccessToken().doOnNext(new Consumer<Authentication>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void accept(Authentication authentication) throws Exception {
                                        update(authentication);
                                    }
                                });
                        }
                    }
                    return Observable.error(throwable);
                }
            });
        }
    })
    .subscribe(new Observer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Log.e("subscribe", "TOKEN : " + preferences.getString("access_token", ""));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Void value) {
            Log.e("onNext", "TOKEN : " + preferences.getString("access_token", ""));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.e("Complete", "____ COMPLETE");
        }
    });
```

The keypoint here is "how to modify/update the existing source observable when `.retryWhen()` operator resubscribe to the source observable"